# Python: Can not get results from simple apply_sync call

Tags: python, multiprocessing, apply-async

I'm trying to use `apply_sync()` inside a class object in order to process live signal from external sensors.
The processes are created but I'm stuck as soon as I'm trying to `get()` the results.

I've tried to use a function inside the class or "outside". No luck.
So I've minimized the code in order to resolve the issue.

The following code is not working for me and I do not know why. Any help will be appreciated.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def calrr(Data, numID):
   fe = 1000
   fen = 5
   print(f"test: {fe * fen}")
   return fe, numID

def f(res):
   print("Finished", r)

p = Pool(2)
toto = p.apply_async(calrr, args = ([1], 0), callback = f)

p.close()
toto.get()
```

Edit: to be clearer, the ipython kernel is stuck after I run the last line. Each time, I had to kill the kernel.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by 'not working' (you have to be more specific). I suppose that the processes are created but you don't get the results you expect. If it helps, i copied the program and i got the output test: 5000
Finished (1000, 0)

Comment: Thanks you. On the computer I used, the ipython kernel got stucked. I waited 10 min without any results. I tried it 10 times, same results (huuum same no result in fact). I had to kill the kernel each time. I'm going to try to run this code on a different computer.

Comment: The code looks correct to me except `r` will be undefined in function `f` .

Comment: Yes my mistake. The code is working in command line. But not on our three spyder installation. I do not really care, but my coworkers need spyder. I need to find a workaround.